# Android Dialog customized OnClickListener

Tags: android, listener, android-alertdialog

I have a generic class witch makes a simple dialog popup:

```
public class GenericDialogPopUp {

    public static void genericCreatePopUp(Context context) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage("message body");

    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // do if ok is pressed
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // do if cancel is pressed
        }
    });

    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

and I need to call this method from within Fragment/Activity:

```
GenericDialogPopUp.genericCreatePopUp(getActivity()); / GenericDialogPopUp.genericCreatePopUp(SomeActivity.this);
```

the problem is that I 'd like to create a kind of **listener** to know if ok button from dialog was pressed, then do the stuff in **this**(where I'm calling dialog) class, like:

```
  if(ok_bt)

     private void doPositive(){                //code            }

   else   

     private void doNegative(){                //code            }
```

Comment: create `interface` for this

Comment: can you give me some simple code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `genericCreatePopUp` method will as follows

```
  public static void genericCreatePopUp(Context context, final SimpleListener listener) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage("message body");

    builder.setPositiveButton(okTxt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            listener.onPosBtnClick();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(bt_can, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            listener.onNegBtnClick();
        }
    });

    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        builder.show();
    }
```

SimpleListener interface:

```
  interface SimpleListener {
    void onPosBtnClick();
    void onNegBtnClick();
  }
```

call this from Fragment/Activity:

```
genericCreatePopUp(context, new SimpleListener (){

     @Override
     onPosBtnClick(){
         // your code
     }

     @Override
     onNegBtnClick(){
          // your code
     }
});
```